# Рандомная замена

Tags: php, массивы

Массив $arrtxt сравнивается по значению с массивом $new по ключу который также содержит в себе массив с ключами и после рандомно выводится рядом со схожим значением из массива $arrtxt но почему-то иногда результат пустым выводится, а если обновить страницу то результат отображается. В чем кроется причина понять никак не могу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код

```
$srt = 'Я навестил Ленина в мавзолее';
$arr = explode(' ', $srt);

$a = $arr;
$tmp = null;
$b = array_reduce($a, function($res, $el) use (&$tmp) {
    if ($tmp) {$el = "$tmp $el"; $tmp = null;}
    if (strlen($el)<=2) $tmp = $el;
    else $res[] = $el;
    return $res;
}, array());
if ($tmp) {$b[] = $tmp;}
$arrtxt = $b;


$new = array(
    'Я навестил' => array('Я наведал', 'Я постетил'),
    'в мавзолее' => array('в кремлевском мавзолее', 'в московском мавзолее')
);


$result = array_intersect_key($new, array_flip($arrtxt));

foreach($result as $key=>$item){

 echo $key .' <b>похоже на</b> '.$item[rand(0, count($item))].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Замените:

```
$item[rand(0, count($item))]
```

На:

```
$item[array_rand($item)]
```

Comment: Действительно :>

Answer (score 1):

`$item[rand(0, count($item))]` - Вот тут кроется причина.

У вас в массиве 2 значения, собсна `count($item)` выдаст 2. Получается `rand(0, 2)` - а это уже 3 значения.

Нужно как-то так: `[rand(0, (count($item)-1))]`

Comment: велосипеды тоже код!)

Comment: @Let'ssayPie та я ничего не велосипедил, просто указал автору где его ошибка.